# Why magento 1.7.0.2 not showing newly added categories?

Tags: php, magento

I added the new category through catalog menu. But its not showing the category in front end.

1.Category is under default category.

2.Is Active -Yes

These are the setting I have done with new category. After saving this, When I go to the front end its not displaying the category. How do I make products added under this category appear in front end.

The category id generated is 72 is showing the issue. Below provided is the code which I am using on the .phtml file to display the products of the category id(72). Except category id 72(which is created newly), rest all other category products I am able to retrieve by passing the category id.

```
<?php
    $categoryId = 72;
    //here $categoryId is the id of the category
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
    $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
    $collection->addCategoryFilter($category); //category filter
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
?>
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure with the following things

```
Is Active = yes

Include in Navigation = yes

It must be sub category of Default Category otherwise you would not able see it

clear magento cache
```

Also please make sure that product those which linked to this category must be enabled.

let me know if you still facing any problem

Thanks

Comment: Yes above mentioned points are done already. But still not able to get the result.

Comment: Also by passing the id 72 the site doesn't work. Rest all other id works fine.

Comment: did you reindexing after category creation ?

Comment: Oh God! forgot about reindexing. Thanks! its working fine now.

Comment: please mark this question completed if you got your answer thanks